# Styling of NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos

How to make border and style of NStextField like that (except icon on the right)? Is it custom or built-in?

[image]

Comment: Tip: add a `NSTextField` and explore the settings.

Comment: Of course I did that, checked different properties. I'm new to macOS, what settings are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Border, Background and Font.

Comment: I am not interested in font actually, rather in textfield background. So are you talking about border in layer? I can only set color and width. But it has a little shade on top, how to achieve that?

Comment: I assumed you are using Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set new `CALayer` and play with `isBezeled` and `isBordered` properties before setting colors.

```
let field = NSTextField()
field.layer = CALayer()
field.wantsLayer = true
field.isBezeled = false
field.isEditable = true
field.isBordered = true
field.backgroundColor = NSColor.white
field.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.gray.cgColor
field.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
field.layer?.borderWidth = 1
field.layer?.cornerRadius = 5
```